# How to align the list of text fields with left alignment

Tags: jasper-reports

This how I get the output:

[image: this how i get the output]

I have checked many blogs but still not able to find it.

jrxml:

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
    <reportElement style="Table_TH" x="2" y="25" width="552" height="19" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
        <font fontName="Poppins" size="11" isBold="false"/>
        <paragraph lineSpacing="Single" firstLineIndent="30"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{text}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

I tried to use `<frame>` but still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the property `firstLineIndent` to 0, And put `I.` and `II.` in separate `textField`.